# Missing PHP array grandchild

Tags: php, arrays

I have some code for building a HTML table from PHP.

```
<?php

function new_table($class)
{
    $table = array('class' => $class, 'tr' => array());

    return $table;
}

function new_tr(&$table, $class)
{
    $tr = array('class' => $class, 'td' => array());

    $table['tr'][] = $tr;

    return $tr;
}

function new_td(&$tr, $class, $content)
{
    $td = array('class' => $class, 'content' => $content);

    $tr['td'][] = $td;

    return $td;
}
?>
```

Usage:

```
    $table = new_table('admin whoami');

    $tr = new_tr($table, 'head');
    new_td($tr, 'field', 'Field');
    new_td($tr, 'value', 'Value');

    $tr = new_tr($table, 'body');
    new_td($tr, 'field', 'Name');
    new_td($tr, 'value', $my_name);

    echo '--- tr ---'.chr(10);
    var_dump($tr);

    echo '--- table ---'.chr(10);
    var_dump($table);
```

And the result:

```
--- tr ---
array(2) {
  ["class"]=>
  string(4) "body"
  ["td"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(5) "field"
      ["content"]=>
      string(4) "Name"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(5) "value"
      ["content"]=>
      string(5) "user0"
    }
  }
}
--- table ---
array(2) {
  ["class"]=>
  string(12) "admin whoami"
  ["tr"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(4) "head"
      ["td"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(4) "body"
      ["td"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you note, var_dump($tr) correctly dumps the tr, including child td elements.

However, var_dump($table), while correctly var_dumping the tr elements, does not var_dump the grandchild td elements -- note the empty array ["td"]=> array(0) { }

Do you know why this might be happening?

Does it have something to do with the returned $tr element being a copy, not a reference, of a $table['tr'] element? In which case, why does adding a tr to the table work, when adding a td to a tr doesn't?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd take a more object oriented approach on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your new_tr() function:

```
function new_tr(&$table, $class)
{
    $tr = array('class' => $class, 'td' => array());

    $table['tr'][] = $tr;

    return $tr;
}
```

The way you created $tr here, means it's a regular variable that will be copied when necessary. It does get added to $table, because that is a reference.

PHP uses copy on write, so when the code returns the $tr you add to $table and the $tr you return are actually still one and the same variable.

But when you go and write to it in new_td(), PHP determines it needs to make a copy because it's not a reference to something. So at this point the $tr in your calling script and the corresponding $tr in your $table array are actually two separate variables/values. So new_td() got a copy of that $tr, instead of the exact same one you created in new_tr().

To fix this, you need to make the new_tr function actually create a reference to the TR and also return the TR it created as a reference:

```
// Return the created TR as a reference by adding the ampersand here.
function &new_tr(&$table, $class)
{
    $tr = array('class' => $class, 'td' => array());

    // The TR in $table needs to be a reference to the value we're returning 
    // because we want to modify this exact variable instead of some copy.
    $table['tr'][] =& $tr;

    return $tr;
}
```

Now when you run it and your code calls new_td($tr), it is actually modifying the variable that you added to $table:

```
$table = new_table('admin whoami');
$tr    =& new_tr($table, 'head');
new_td($tr, 'field', 'Field');

// EDIT: Note how you need to create a reference here aswell. This is to
// make $tr a reference to the return value of new_tr() instead of a value copy.  
$tr =& new_tr($table, 'body');

echo '--- table ---'.chr(10);
var_dump($table);
```

results in:

```
--- table ---
array(2) {
  ["class"]=>
  string(12) "admin whoami"
  ["tr"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(4) "head"
      ["td"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["class"]=>
          string(5) "field"
          ["content"]=>
          string(5) "Field"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    &array(2) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(4) "body"
      ["td"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. The ampersand in the function definition was something I didn't know how to do. This has both solved the immediate problem and also taught me how to apply this to other situations. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$table['tr'][] = $tr;
```

This line will add the created `tr` to the array, but note that once you return `$tr`, it lives it's own life. When you modify it, the value won't be updated in the `table`.